# Refactor object keys to avoid tautology

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object that I use to get proper position values for my elements.
How do I optimize this object to avoid tautology in key department?

Currently my object looks like this below:

```
function animPos(animName, position) {
    const availibleValues = {
        onLoadAnim: position,
        greetingAnim: position,
        textAnim: currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505,
        inputAnim: currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505,
        evaluationAnim: currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505,
        testAnim: currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505,
        passedAnim: currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505,
        default: 251.5,
    };
    return availibleValues[animName];
}
```

I have no idea how to refactor this.

Comment: "to avoid tautology" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Peter B , textAnim, inputAnim, evaluationAnim, testAnim, passedAnim all have the same value. Is there a way to connect them all to that single value?

Comment: Create a variable for `var x = currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505;` then use it i.e. `const availibleValues = {
            onLoadAnim: position,
            greetingAnim: position,
            testAnim: x,
            passedAnim: x,
            default: 251.5,
        };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could use a `switch` statement:

```js
var currentAnim = 1; // needed to make sample work
var AnimRight = 1;

function animPos(animName, position) {
  switch (animName) {
    // first group
    case "onLoadAnim":
    case "greetingAnim":
      return position;
    // second group
    case "textAnim":
    case "inputAnim":
    case "evaluationAnim":
    case "testAnim":
    case "passedAnim":
      return currentAnim === AnimRight ? 0 : 505;
  };
  // default
  return 251.5;
}

console.log("inputAnim    -> " + animPos("inputAnim", 15));
console.log("greetingAnim -> " + animPos("greetingAnim", 15));
console.log("unknown      -> " + animPos("unknown", 15));
```